# Remove new line in Postgresql log before sent to Graylog

Tags: logs, postgresql

i want to remove all new line in Postgresql log before sent them to Graylog.
Example,

```
2018-08-30 00:00:00 WIB [29212] hi_user@myDatabase 172.21.253.44 LOG:  duration: 1044.000 ms  execute 32:
                            SELECT
                                    talk_id,
                                    product_id,
                                    shop_id,
                                    user_id,
                                    message,
                                    total_comment,
                                    create_time,
                                    status,
                                    fraud_status
                            FROM
                                    ws_talk
                            WHERE
                                    ws_talk.status = 1 AND ws_talk.product_id IN(298932598,309360018,300809172,309360017,300809175,300809174,300809173,298932597,25748655) AND create_time > '2018-01-01 00:00:00'
                                            AND ws_talk.shop_id = 216771
                            ORDER BY talk_id DESC
                            LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0
```

That should be like this

```
2018-08-30 00:00:00 WIB [29212] hi_user@myDatabase 172.21.253.44 LOG:  duration: 1044.000 ms  execute 32:
SELECT talk_id, product_id, shop_id, user_id, message, total_comment, create_time, status, fraud_status FROM ws_talk WHERE ws_talk.status = 1 AND ws_talk.product_id IN(298932598,309360018,300809172,309360017,300809175,300809174,300809173,298932597,25748655) AND create_time > '2018-01-01 00:00:00' AND ws_talk.shop_id = 216771 ORDER BY talk_id DESC LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0
```

I think, it's better.

And this is how it looks like in Graylog
[image: Postgresql in Graylog]